# SQLAlchemy: session.add

Tags: session, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to add two new object using session.add(object) twice..but the first object disappear on session.commit()...why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

they must be of different object for them to be added to the session.commit().

Comment: it was a different object..ok, let say this is sample of my code: // assume the session and all python module have been imported before

obj1 = object1()
obj2 = object2()

obj1.fullname = 'fullname'
obj1.lastname = 'lastname'

obj2.city = 'city'
obj2.state = 'state'

session.add_all([obj1, obj2])
try:
    session.commit()
except:
    session.rollback()

// this was ok in sqlalchemy v0.5.3, but it face problem in v0.5.5
// the first object was missing when session.commit() is called

Comment: well it looks like you forgot that very crucial detail from your OP. If you could have added that to your OP, it would make life for others a lot easier. And as zzzeek have mentioned, try posting that information to sqlalchemy's mailing-loist.

Answer (score 0):

if the difference between 0.5.3 and 0.5.5 is all that changes, you probably want to create a fully illustrating example and post it on the mailing list at http://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy/ .